# Why does this function return boolean values?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering why this function returns true and false values? I wasn't expecting numbers necessarily, but am confused - is it something to do with how the forEach method works?

```js
function canDrive(...years){
  years.forEach(cur => console.log((2020 - cur) >= 21));
}


canDrive(1990, 1999, 1965)
```

Comment: `(2020 - cur) >= 21)`  you are comparing the left argument to the one on the right  also `forEach` call back doesn't return anything

Comment: Right the fundamentals - thank you! This makes sense.

Comment: The function doesn't `return` anything. It does however `console.log(…)` boolean values, the results of the comparison `(2020 - cur) >= 21`.

Comment: Because the answer to `>=` is always `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is "returning" boolean values because there is a comparison statement inside of the console.log:

```
console.log((2020 - cur) >= 21)
```

This is converting it to a boolean. (it is actually logging, not returning as @Bergi mentioned in the comments)